# Laravel model relationship method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relation

I have 3 tables

1. User (id,name,mail,mobile)
2. Contest (id,contest_name,contest_description)
3. Contest_user (id,user_id,contest_id)

I want to write a has many contest user method in the contest model also I need the user details from the method.
Kindly tell me how can I get the desired result.

[Model Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAvJW.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Contest;

use App\Model\Project\ContestUsers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contest';

    protected $fillable = ['name','description'];
    public $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    //I want to get user details from this method
    public function project_contest_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContestUsers::class, 'contest_id', 'id')->whereNull('deleted_at');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, edit the question with the code you tried to write.

Comment: Kindly go through the [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) relation.

Comment: You don't need a `ContestUsers` Model. this is a pivot table for a belongsToMany relationship. Also take a look at the Laravel naming conventions: it wil make things easier: (your namespace should be in UpperCamelCase, table name 'contests' for a model, 'contest_user' for the pivot table... )

Answer (score 0):

`contest_user` is a pivot table for `users` and `contests` and should not have a model class.

The nature of the relation between User and Contest is a many to many, so you need to use `belongsToMany()` relation in both sides

**Contest.php**

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**User.php**

```php
public function contests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contest::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have done, based on my experience, it's already a good thing that you normalize the many to many relationship. But what N69S said is also correct, that pivot table should not have a Model class, so you need to make your own convention to not use the Model class to create/update/delete (read is fine by me) and if you still want to stick to this method, what you need to do now is just defining the relationships for each of the Models.

User.php:

```
public function contest_user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContestUser::class);
}
```

ContestUser.php:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function contest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contest::class);
}
```

Contest.php:

```
public function contest_user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContestUser::class);
}
```